# iOS - When i create NSManagedObject subclass -> linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I am creating a new project for iOS.
 I use the template Master-Detail, and the framework coredata: If I click the xcdatamodel file and then I go to

```
Editor-> Created NSManagedObject subclass
```

I get the error:

```
Apple Mach-O Linker error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The project is totally new.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to delete those files because they are duplicates. Xcode now generates and manages core data files automatically. So you don't need to create them manually through Editor-> Created NSManagedObject subclass.